# post_count not working

Tags: posts, count

I've fixed my initial problem but I'd like to know what I was doing wrong.

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
        'post_parent' => '43',
        'post_count' => '3',
    );
    $my_related_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Displays 4 results, where I expected 3.  I fixed the problem by doing:

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
        'post_parent' => '43',
        'post_count' => '3',
        'posts_per_page' => '3'
    );
    $my_related_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

But what was I doing wrong?  Changing post_count seemed to have little or no effect.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`post_count` is not a parameter of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) argument.

`post_count` is a property used to get the number of posts being displayed. For example, `echo $my_related_posts->post_count;` will display the number of posts being displayed.

Comment: Ahhhhhh....  Is `posts_per_page` what I should be using for what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `posts_per_page` is the number of posts you want to be returned from that query.